# How to display a warning message just below the message received in IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, sms, message, imessagefilter

I'm using MessageFilter Extension to filter the messages in **Messages** app.When a user opens a message, I want to warn the the user that received message is suspicious. So for this I want to display a Customised text or message just below the messages. I have attached screenshots for reference. Can any help me, how can I implement this.

### Image showing the 'content Filtered by AppName'

[image: Image showing the 'content Filtered by AppName']

### Images showing the content below the message

[image: Images showing the content below the message]

I have seen some of the apps have implemented this feature but I don't have any idea about this. I have seen that after filtering a message to junk , just below the message it is written that **Filtered by iOS App** shown in first image.

Comment: Add button in tableview footer or simply add a subview in the tableview from storyboard and add button and message in the subview.

Comment: @SupriyoDey, I want to show the customised message  below the message in the native Message App in iPhone as shown in ScreenShots attached.